# Is there a way to get Instagram @Mention History via API or otherwise?

Tags: instagram

The native application doesn't show *all* the activity, only the most recent.

Therefore I lose 70-90% of my notifications overnight. There must be a way to get all that historical data.

Comment: no API currently for notification or @mentions :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I told you can't, but, thinking.. you can. :)

The API don't provide that facility.. You can check all endpoints here: http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/

But you can iterate over all your medias an get all comments and likes. If you store it locally, after,  will be possible to request API again and check your new unseen interactions.

It will work for likes and comments.